# How can I count objects in jq (not in an array)

Tags: json, jq

I have some json input that comes as a list of objects (not as a json array) like, for which I want to count the number of active, and the number of inactive:

```
{
  "key" : "state",
  "value" : "active"
}
{
  "key" : "state",
  "value" : "active"
}
{
  "key" : "state",
  "value" : "active"
}
{
  "key" : "state",
  "value" : "inactive"
}
```

I want to transform using only JQ (in fact it will be handled by jackson-jq in java code, so I can not use some shell tricks).

I tried many things, like `select(.value == "active") | length` to get the number of active, but  it is always handle object per object.
Even when using reduce, it is always handled object per object.

Example of output is :

```
2
2
2
```

(I have 3 objects with 2 fields that match value="active)

The output that I expect is :

```
3
```

[Here](https://jqplay.org/s/-8E8lVluCn) is a playground with my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid "slurping" the input, you would use either `reduce` or `foreach`.  Here's a suitable abstraction built from `reduce`:

```
def count(s; f; g):
  reduce s as $s ([0,0];
    if $s|f then .[0]+=1 else . end
    | if $s|g then .[1]+=1 else . end);
```

With this, you would invoke jq with the -n command-line option and run a query such as:

```
count(inputs|.value; .=="active"; .=="inactive")
```

Notice that one cannot use `count/1` (defined analogously) twice since `inputs` consumes the input stream.

Comment: If you can use options, you can use `jq -s '[.[] | select(.value == "active")] | length'`.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer @peak 
This is the kind of result I need, however I must preserve input as many computations will need to be applied, and possibly multiple times. 
Also in jqplay, the output seemed to be off by one, not taking the first element into account
https://jqplay.org/s/J2x3FjpLV9

Comment: Don’t forget the -n command-line option.  You may still be able to use this reduce-based approach even with other requirements.

Comment: Marking @peak answer as the correct answer
After some tweaking, I have been able to use something very close without using `inputs`.

Many thanks for your help.

Note: I can not use the -n options as I am using jq-jackson in java. But a similar configuration must be in place in the software I am using , as this solution does work.

Comment: If you cannot add the -n option or -s optin, then you will have to make sure that you don't lose the first JSON entity in your input stream, e.g. by using `.,inputs` instead of just `inputs`.